# mvn spring-boot:run equivalent in Eclipse

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have seen tutorials where they specify to run Maven project as `mvn spring-boot:run`. I have been using `SpringApplication.run` as my way to run my SpringBoot apps.

I do not know the equivalent of those tutorials in Eclipse. How can I run the same command `mvn spring-boot:run` in my IDE.(I am using Eclipse on Windows)

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse,

Right click project - > Run As -> Maven Build.

In the goals, enter spring-boot:run

Answer (score 1):

You can also run the project as Java Application:

Right click project -> Run As -> Java Application -> Select the Class from which you want the application to boot(the one with @SpringBootApplication).